# Unable to Pass Variable from Controller to Drop Down

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7, laravelcollective

I'm trying to get data from a table called solutions and view the solution names in a dropdown list on a form called products.

I've created a provider called DynamicDropdown in App/Providers.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Dropdown;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DynamicDropdown extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('product_array', Dropdown::all());
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\DynamicDropdown;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $select = [];
        foreach ($view as $data) {
            $select [$data->id] = $data->solutionname;
        }

        return view('products.products', compact('select'));
    }
}
```

I've called the select variable in the view but unfortunately, I'm getting an undefined variable error.

**Blade**

```
<div class="form-group <?php echo e($errors->has('solution') ? 'has-error' : ''); ?>">
    <?php echo Form::label('solution', 'Solution', ['class' => 'control-label']); ?>
    <?php echo Form::select('solution', $select, null,
        ('' == 'required') ? ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required'] : ['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
    <?php echo $errors->first('solution', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>'); ?>
</div>
```

Error Message is...

> ErrorException thrown with message "Undefined variable: select (View:
>   E:\Laravel\IBMint\resources\views\products\products\form.blade.php)

I tried many ways to fix it. But still could not find a solution. Appreciate if someone could assist.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are actually calling the $select variable on the wrong form. You return a view

```
  return view('products.products', compact('select'));
```

which means get the view **products.blade.php** on the folder **products under the view folder.**
and based on the error you put the $select variable on the **form.blade.php**.

Fix will be you return the view form.blade.php like this.

```
 return view('products.products.form', compact('select'));
```